# Create dynamic copy of filter list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list with names in column A Sheet 1. Each name appears several times. I would like to list each name once in Sheet 2. Basically sheet 2 is a copy of the filter list in column A sheet 1, but I would like it to be **dynamic** so that it **stays updated** with the list in column A.

i.e: if a new name is added to column A sheet 1 several times - the list in Sheet 2 **will add it** once.

Answer (score 1):

*Actually you need to generate Unique list of names in Sheet 2 and this array formula solves the issue.*

[image]

- Enter this formula in Cell `C2` of Sheet 2, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill it down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$118:$A$132, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1, Sheet1!$A$118:$A$132), 0)),"")}
  ```

## Edited:

*I would like to suggest to create **Dynamic Named Range**, to auto update the Unique name list in Sheet 2, as soon you add names in Sheet 1.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Click **Define Name** or, press **Ctrl+F3** to reach to *Name Manger*, then click the **New** button.
- Write an appropriate name in *Name* box and this formula in *Refers to*.

  ```
  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$118, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A), 1)
  ```
- Finally enter this array Formula in Cell `C2` of Sheet 2, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(NameList, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1, NameList), 0)),"")}
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*